# Вызов метода из другого класса

Tags: delphi

Пишу графический компонент - наследник `TGraphicControl`. Перерисовка происходит по методу `Paint`. Для удобства в инспекторе объектов сгруппировал некоторые свойства при помощи свойства-объекта, наследник `TPersistent`. Никак не могу додуматься, как вызвать метод `Paint` в другом классе для перерисовки компонента при изменении свойства.

**UPD**

Решил проблему так

```
type
  TTicksY = class (TPersistent)
  private
    FCount: Byte;
    FWidth: Byte;
    FOnPaint: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure SetCount(const Value: Byte);
    procedure SetWidth(const Value: Byte);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    procedure Assign(Source: TPersistent); override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property Width: Byte read FWidth write SetWidth;
    property Count: Byte read FCount write SetCount;
    property OnPaint:  TNotifyEvent read FOnPaint write FOnPaint;
  end;
```

Основной класс:

```
TAVGraph = class(TGraphicControl)
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FTicksY: TTicksY;
    procedure setTicksY(const Value: TTicksY);
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(aowner:TComponent); override;
    destructor Destory;
  published
    { Published declarations }
     procedure _Paint(Sender: TObject);
     property TicksY: TTicksY read FTicksY write setTicksY;
  end;

constructor TAVGraph.Create(Aowner: TComponent);
begin
 inherited Create(Aowner);
 If Owner Is TWinControl Then Parent := AOwner As TWinControl;// добавил это
 ControlStyle:=ControlStyle+ [csReplicatable];
 FTicksY:=TTicksY.Create;
 FTicksY.OnPaint:=_Paint;
end;

procedure TTicksY.SetWidth(const Value: Byte);
begin
  FWidth := Value;
  if Assigned(FOnPaint) then  fOnPaint(Self); //это
end;

procedure TAVGraph._Paint(Sender: TObject);
begin
 Paint;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

А не проще в самом классе сделать, чтобы автоматом происходила перерисовка при изменении свойства

```
TMyControl = class(TCustomControl)
private
  FBackgroundColor: TColor;
  procedure SetBackgroundColor(NewColor: TColor);
published
  property BackgroundColor: TColor read FBackgroundColor write SetBackgroundColor;
end;

...

procedure TMyControl.SetBackgroundColor(NewColor: TColor);
begin
  if FBackgroundColor <> NewColor then
  begin
    FBackgroundColor := NewColor;
    Invalidate;
  end;
end;
```

и вызывать в SetBackgroundColor ваш Paint.
Код дернул из Инета, чтобы был понятен принцип.

Comment: Книга по созданию компонент в Delphi:
Создание оригинальных компонент в среде Delphi - Рэй Конопка.

Comment: Смысл всего, чтобы сгруппировать свойства в инспекторе объектов.
Автоматически перерисовать из самого класса - не проблема (как в вашем примере), а вот как из другого класса вызвать Paint, не знаю. 
Книгу смотрел, там только упоминает автор, что такие свойства есть, и все.

Comment: Добавь еще немного кода, чтобы лучше было понятно.

Comment: Добавил кода

Comment: А что вас не устраивает?

Comment: Теперь все устраивает, не могу добавить ответ, поэтому воткнул код в вопрос.

Answer (score -2):

> if Assigned(FOnPaint) then  fOnPaint(Self); //это

Repaint/Refresh etc не спасут ОРД?

> На всякий случай напомню, что сегодня никто Deplhi не использует.

p.s. и, да, не нужно писать бред.